# Bit manipulation: detect if at least 5 bits in byte are set?

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation

What is the best way to check if a minimum number of bits have been set in a binary number?

For example I need to see if at least 5 bits are set to 1 in this sequence:

101100010

I've been looking at using bit masks and the like but am more confused than confident about how this can be done.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: if the bits have meaning I would construct an object that takes the string "101100010" then provides methods to indicate meaningful state

Comment: this is called "hamming weight" by the way. that might assist you in finding an implementation.

Comment: I will leave you with this: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 3):

From http://blog.faultylabs.com/2011.php?p=jsbitfun

```
/*
 popCnt(n)
 Returns the bit population count of n (that is: how many bits in n are set to 1)
 n must be an unsigned integer in the range [0..(2^32)-1]
 This lookup-table-free method is from Kernighan & Ritchie's "The C Programming Language"
 Exercise 2.9 (on page 62 of my copy). Not sure whether they (K&R) are the inventors.
*/
function popCnt(n) {
    n >>>= 0 /* force uint32 */
    for(var popcnt = 0; n; n &= n - 1) {
        popcnt++
    }
    return popcnt
}
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight for details on other algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to learn to work with bits, play around with bitmasks.

If you need a very simple solution just convert the integer to a string representation of its binary value and count number of 1's:

```
var i = 0x1 +0x4 + 0x8 +0x80; // 10001101 in binary
var numberOf1s = i.toString(2).split('1').length-1; // 4
```

so all in all you need just a single line of code to do it:

```
if(<insert your var>.toString(2).split('1').length-1 >=5) {
  //At least 5 bits are set
}
```

Comment: @pimvdb: I agree, it would be simpler, but since the OP asked for "at least 5" I thought id code it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with bitmasks first, especially if trying to learn. It's the most logically simple approach when looking at it as a sequence of bits. (There are a *bunch* of clever tricks that can be done, but first is first and, with a language like JS with a myriad of engines, the implementation might make clever-not-so-clever.)

To test if bit `b` is set, it is set when `input & (1 << b)` is non-0, of course `1 << b` is `00000001` (0x01), `00000010` (0x02), `00000100` (0x04), `00001000` (0x08) and so-on when `b` is 0, 1, 2, 3 and so-on. (Note 1 is `00000001` and how `<<` moves the pattern *left* by `b` bits).

So, for each 0 <= `b` < 8, see if the bit is set. If it is, add one to a counter.

Now we know how many bits in the first octect are set.

Also note that there is only a small finite set of values for `b` we care about. Thus we can eliminate the loop and know each `1 << b` for each loop iteration. (Some browsers like Firefox can process a sequence of bit-wise math operations like this *very very fast* when a single expression.)

Happy coding

---

For fun I decided to create a quick performance test-case of `popCnt` (and `strCount`), as shown in other answers, and a specialized bit-counter, `fastCount8`, that only uses math operations and doesn't try to be overly clever and a `simpleCount8` as described above.

Granted that both `fastCount8` (and `simpleCount8`) are limited to a single octect (first byte), but for this *particular* case `fastCount8` is very much faster in *certain* browsers. (It is *significantly* faster in FF8 but only marginally faster in IE9 and *slower* in Chrome 16.) As expected, `strCount` is substantially slower than `popCnt` and `simpleCount8` doesn't fair much better.

Here is the [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/bit-count8), and `fastCount8`:

```
function fastCount8(n) {
    // >> has higher precedence than &
    return (n >> 0 & 1)
      + (n >> 1 & 1)
      + (n >> 2 & 1)
      + (n >> 3 & 1)
      + (n >> 4 & 1)
      + (n >> 5 & 1)
      + (n >> 6 & 1)
      + (n >> 7 & 1)
}
```

---

Updated performance test-cases for `lookup8`, `lookupN` (and some variants), `fastCount8N` and `fastCount8N2`. The results are quite spectacular: FF8 does some *absolutely amazing* math optimizations and the other browsers (I tested) can't even come close to keeping up for the given expression. Also, the other results can be *somewhat surprising* and showcase how different browsers optimize different things...

...all in all, `lookup8` and `lookupN2b` look the most consistent across browsers... at least with the given range of `n` applied.

Comment: if performance is your primary concern, and only worried about 8 bits, then I would just go with a look-up table.

Comment: @32bitkid Updated for you. That is actually *slower* than `fastCount8` in FF8. (FF does some pretty amazing math-heavy optimizations, these results seem pretty common.)

Comment: Hmm, repeat runs show different results, perhaps more testers :p